# How To Make More Functional?

Tags: c#, f#

I'm a c# guy who has learned JavaScript recently and thinking of going down the f# path.  I love the functional nature of JavaScript but have trouble bring it into my c# code.  I look at the below block of code and it really feels ugly.  For those that are naturally bent towards functional programming, what would be a better way to do this block in either c# (or even f#).

(or am I barking up the wrong tree looking to improve it)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current Tenant based on tenantNameOverride if present, 
    ///   otherwise uses urlHost to figure it out
    /// case independent
    /// if urlHost and tenantNameOverride empty then 
    ///   throws exception
    /// if tenantNameOverride specified and not found
    ///   throw exception
    /// if tenantNameOverride not specified and there 
    ///   is no default tenant, then throw exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tenants"></param>
    /// <param name="urlHost"></param>
    /// <param name="tenantNameOverride"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Tenant GetTenantBasedOnUrlHost(
        List<Tenant> tenants, string urlHost=null,
        string tenantNameOverride=null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlHost) && 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantNameOverride))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "urlHost or tenantName must be specified");
        }

        Tenant tenant;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantNameOverride))
        {
            tenant = tenants.
                FirstOrDefault(a => a.DomainName.ToLower().Equals(urlHost)) ??
                     tenants.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Default);
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException
                    ("tenantName must be specified, no default tenant found");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tenant = tenants.FirstOrDefault
                (a => a.Name.ToLower() == tenantNameOverride.ToLower());
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException
                    ("tenantNameOverride specified and not found");
            }
        }
        return tenant;
    }
```

/********************* update below *****************/

Per Jon Skeet's suggestion, I've made two methods. With the exception of the error check at the top for empty string violations which I'm not sure we can easily avoid in c#. Throwing an exception also feels a little odd on not found but for my purposes, these methods should always find a tenant and if not that is unexpected and an exception seems reasonable.

This does seem cleaner and sticks better to the design guideline of single responsibility.  Maybe that is what I did not like about my solution and it had nothing to do with functional or non-functional.

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Return tenant based on URL (or return default tenant if exists)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tenants"></param>
    /// <param name="urlHost"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Tenant GetTenantBasedOnUrl(
        List<Tenant> tenants, string urlHost)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlHost))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "urlHost must be specified");
        }

        var tenant = tenants.
            FirstOrDefault(a => a.DomainName.ToLower().Equals(urlHost)) ??
                     tenants.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Default);
        if (tenant == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException
                ("tenant not found based on URL, no default found");
        }
        return tenant;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get exact tenant name match and do not return default even 
    /// if exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tenants"></param>
    /// <param name="tenantNameOverride"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Tenant GetTenantByName(List<Tenant> tenants,
        string tenantNameOverride)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantNameOverride))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "tenantNameOverride or tenantName must be specified");
        }

        var tenant = tenants.FirstOrDefault
            (a => a.Name.ToLower() == tenantNameOverride.ToLower());
        if (tenant == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException
                ("No tenant Found (not checking for default)");
        }
        return tenant;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you prefer to write it? For working code, codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: For one thing, why is this one method rather than a single method for doing it based on URL and another based on tenant name? You're saying that *exactly* one of those can be specified... so make two methods.

Comment: For starters, you could improve the code by preventing the need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Does *every* `Tenant` have a `Default`, apart from `DomainName`? Why isn't there a ´default tenant' instead?

Comment: @MarkSeemann - there is a bool Default attribute in every tenant record.  My contract with the Tenant table is that only one row can be marked as default.  I do this because it makes it easy to find a default value and I can easily keep it in the same table (relational db). Open to other suggestions but that's not really related to my question.

Comment: This doesn't answer your immediate question but rewriting this as you learn F# would actually be a great way to learn it. https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/functional-architecture-fsharp/table-of-contents

Comment: I've updated the question to include an answer as suggested by @JonSkeet and put some comments in.  Maybe my problem is not functional in nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem in F#.

First, if I understand the requirements correctly, the caller of the function must supply *either* a domain name, *or* a tenant name to search for. In C#, such an exclusive rule is difficult to model, which leads to the rule that at least one must be specified, but if *both* are specified, one of the arguments take precedence.

While such a rule is difficult to define using C#'s type system, it's trivial to declare in F#, using a Discriminated Union:

```ml
type TenantCriterion =
| DomainName of Uri
| Name of string
```

This means that a criterion searching for a tenant can be *either* a `DomainName` *or* a *Name*, but never both.

In my definition of `DomainName`, I changed the type to `System.Uri`. When you're dealing with URLs, it's generally safer to use `Uri` values than `string` values.

Instead of converting `string` values to lower case, it's safer to compare them using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, if that's what you want, since there are all sorts of subtle localization issues if you convert e.g. Turkish strings to lower case (that conversion is lossy).

Finally, I changed the query to return `Tenant option` instead of throwing exceptions. In Functional Programming, we prefer to avoid exceptions. If you want more detailed exception handling than `option` you can [use the Either monad](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop).

All that said, here's a possible implementation of the function to find a tenant:

```ml
let findTenant tenants = function
    | DomainName u ->
        let t = tenants |> List.tryFind (fun x -> x.DomainName = u)
        match t with
        | Some t -> Some t
        | None -> tenants |> List.tryFind (fun x -> x.IsDefault)
    | Name n ->
        tenants
        |> List.tryFind
            (fun x -> n.Equals(x.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

This function has the type `Tenant list -> TenantCriterion -> Tenant option`. If you want more lazy evaluation, you can replace `List.tryFind` with `Seq.tryFind`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSeemann I kind of get it.  I did watch a few clips of your PS video (I'm an author there also so appreciate the efforts to make these videos).  I can see how much work you put into trying to get people (me) into shifting their (our) frame of reference.  I need to find time to watch the rest now (and the intro to f#).  The VS F# web project looks really sad.  MS should fix that.  Feels a little like a train wreck.

Comment: FWIW, for Web API, I just do this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/08/23/how-to-create-a-pure-f-aspnet-web-api-project Once you've tried it a couple of times, it's not that bad, and you only have to do it at the beginning of a code base.

Comment: Since that video was created there have been a couple of community created templates for visual studio which can get you setup easily.  Just New Project->Online->Templates->Visual F#->ASP.NET and then select one.